# SVG Locally Hosted Google Fonts

Tags: css, svg

I am having trouble using a Google font in an SVG image. I am locally hosting the Amatica SC font and am using the following CSS to style text:

```
<defs>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Amatica SC', cursive;
            src: local('AmaticaSC Bold'), local('AmaticaSC-Bold'), url(Amatica_SC/AmaticaSC-Bold.ttf), format('truetype');
        }

        text {
            font-family: 'Amatica SC', cursive;
        }
    </style>
</defs>
```

Note that this code is inside the SVG tags. Unfortunately, this does not work and the text displays as cursive instead of Amatica SC. Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: how are you viewing the image? are you hosting it on a webserver and then going to the svg file's url directly?

Comment: No, I am designing the SVG in my desktop. So the font is just in a local folder. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you're using Chrome it's security model prevents loading of files from different directories. Firefox might work though.